# Using the for list comprehension returns unexpected results

Tags: clojure, list-comprehension

so I try this code

```
(for [x (range 1 8) y (range 1 8) :while (and (< x y) (even? x))] [x y])
```

and get back ()

but I try this:

```
(for [x (range 1 8) y (range 1 8) :while (and (< y x) (even? x))] [x y])
```

and I get the desired result.
What effect did changing the positions of x and y have? The first snippet shouldn't return an empty list.. after all there have to be some even x's smaller than y

Comment: The `:while` doesn't bind to the whole `for` construct, only to the part iterating over `y` and then *restarts* every time `x` is incremented. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Also see http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for and look at the part demonstrating the difference between `:when` and `:while`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Clojure, `(for [x (range 1 8) y (range 1 8)] [x y])` returns the cartesian product of `x` and `y` with `y` running from `1` to `7` for each and every iteration of `x`.

From the repl:

```
user=> (for [x (range 1 8) y (range 1 8)] [x y])
([1 1] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [1 6] [1 7] [2 1] [2 2] [2 3] [2 4] [2 5] [2 6] [2 7] [3 1] [3 2] [3 3] [3 4] [3 5] [3 6] [3 7] [4 1] [4 2] [4 3] [4 4] [4 5] [4 6] [4 7] [5 1] [5 2] [5 3] [5 4] [5 5] [5 6] [5 7] [6 1] [6 2] [6 3] [6 4] [6 5] [6 6] [6 7] [7 1] [7 2] [7 3] [7 4] [7 5] [7 6] [7 7])
```

In your examples, `:while` is associated with `y` and not `x`. So the `:while` applies for every iteration of `y` and then *restarts* after the next iteration of `x`.

To make this clearer, note that you can also associate `:while` with `x`:

```
user=> (for [x (range 1 8) :while (odd? x) y (range 1 8)] [x y])
([1 1] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [1 6] [1 7])
```

which runs the loop *while* `x` is odd, then breaks.

So in your first example, `:while` breaks on every single iteration on `y` when `y` equals `1` because there is no value of `x` for which `(and (< x 1) (even? x))` holds `true`.

Your second example, on the other hand, works because even though `:while` breaks on the first iteration of `y` because `(< 1 1)` yields `false`, the second iteration of `y` succeeds because `x` starts from `2`, so if `y` is `1`, and `(and (< y x) (even? x))` is `(and (< 1 2) (even? 2))` which evaluates to `true`.

See http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for for more details. Especially the part showing the difference between `:when` and `:while`.